# Как включить vpn в ubuntu через консоль?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vpn

У меня есть хост,порт ,логин и пароль ssl vpn ,нужно через консоль подключиться к нему . В windows это делал через forticlient в gui , теперь это же нужно на ubuntu docker сделать

Comment: Эээ? А OpenVPN?

Comment: А как настроить его именно для моей задачи?